# GWT ie8 timeout 12002

Tags: http, gwt, internet-explorer-8, rpc

we have a bug with ie8(under XP), and ie9 (under 7) doing several RPC GWT calls. Eventually, one of the calls fires but server responds with a reset (RST) and the application keeps waiting the result until a 12002 http error is received (12002 seems to mean TimeOut) after some minutes.

Some keys:

- We can not reproduce the bug in Other browsers.
- We have fired hundreds of the same RPC calls using prototype.js in ie8 and it never fails! So, we can only reproduce it inside gwt code.
- it is a random thing. some time it happens three seconds after the first call others three minutes after.
- in a client with windows server 2003 the http error is 12030 instead of 12002 and it happens immediatly.

[image: RST problem]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a GWT problem. This is an AJAX problem.
In addition I've seen it can happen in FF too.
But IE with nested callbacks really aggravated this.

The link below really helped, but it did not solve the problem 100%.

[Why does IE issue random XHR 408/12152 responses using jQuery post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731420/why-does-ie-issue-random-xhr-408-12152-responses-using-jquery-post)

It suggests that the problem will be solved if you close the HTTP connection for each request on the servlet.

The problem disappeared when we moved to Server 2008/Tomcat. 
With Server 2003 the IIS was full of errors.

[Also this link is useful](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/76673)

Comment: I tried to send a "Connection:close" from server but it keep hanging... We don't know what else to do...

Comment: connection close helped me, another thing that helped was to eliminate nested callbacks, also i used GET wherever i could. the server 2008 was the biggest improvement, there is a link that explains this pretty well, but what happens is that the current request resets the previous request before it completes. What causes this must be a combination of XMLHTTPRequest + POST + server configuration. it could help to test this with another http server